# Interpolating three textures in one fragment in GLSL (webgl)

Tags: glsl, webgl

I would like to be able to blend three different textures in one fragment so that they interpolate equally.

I managed to get two textures (textureColor1,textureColor2) to blend across the fragment by using a third texture (textureColor3) which was a black to white gradient. I would like to do something similar with three textures but it would be great to be able to interpolate three textures without having to include another texture as a mask. Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
vec4 textureColor1 = texture2D(uSampler, vec2(vTextureCoord1.s, vTextureCoord1.t));
vec4 textureColor2 = texture2D(uSampler2, vec2(vTextureCoord2.s, vTextureCoord2.t));
vec4 textureColor3 = texture2D(uSampler3, vec2(vTextureCoord1.s, vTextureCoord1.t));
vec4 finalColor = mix(textureColor2, textureColor1, textureColor3.a);
```

Comment: It's not entirely clear what it is you're trying to achieve. What do you mean when you say that you want the three textures to "blend equally?"

Comment: Why cant you just divide every textureColorX by 3, and then add those values? Or hand wirte any "interpolation algorithm" you want.

Comment: Thanks for the help! I was hoping to blend three different textures similarly too how the shader would interpolate three different colors assigned to each vertex. Currently I have a hand written algorithm that blends the textures based on their alphas. I was looking for it to interpolate them as mentioned above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want them all to blend equally, then you can simply do something like:

```
finalColor.x = (textureColor1.x + textureColor2.x + textureColor3.x)/3.0;
finalColor.y = (textureColor1.y + textureColor2.y + textureColor3.y)/3.0;
finalColor.z = (textureColor1.z + textureColor2.z + textureColor3.z)/3.0;
```

You could also pass in texture weights as floats. For example, Texture1 might have a weight of 0.5, Texture2 a weight of 0.3 and Texture3 a weight of 0.2. As long as the weights add to 1.0, you can simply multiply them by the texture values. It's just like finding a [weighted average](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weighted_mean).

Comment: I think the weighting would get me closer to what I want to achieve but I do want some blending throughout the fragment. Similar to the triangle (one fragment) shown here : [http://learningwebgl.com/blog/?p=134]

Comment: Ah, so you'd essentially want to have different weights at different pixels then, i.e. a gradient? If your store the weights as vertex attributes you can pass that into the pixel shader. If you want to control the weight of each pixel though the only options are storing the weights in the alpha channels of the existing textures, or adding another texture. If you don't need the alpha for transparency, using the alpha channels is the better option to go with.

Comment: Makes sense, thanks! I think I'll stick with storing the weights in the alpha channel. Seems to make sense and I can vary it by texture... also simplifies my shader code : `vec4 textureColor1 = texture2D(uSampler, vec2(vTextureCoord1.s, vTextureCoord1.t));
 vec4 textureColor2 = texture2D(uSampler, vec2(vTextureCoord2.s, vTextureCoord2.t));
 
 vec4 finalColor = mix(textureColor2, textureColor1, textureColor1.a);`

Answer (score 0):

Interpolate 3 textures using weights:

Assume your have weight from 0 to 1 for each texture type
And you have normalized weights - so they equal to 1 in sum
And you input weights as vec3 into shader

```
varying/uniform/... vec3 weights;
main {
resultColor.x = (texel0.x * weights.x + texel1.x * weights.y + texel2.x * weights.z);
resultColor.y = (texel0.y * weights.x + texel1.y * weights.y + texel2.y * weights.z);
resultColor.z = (texel0.z * weights.x + texel1.z * weights.y + texel2.z * weights.z);
...
}
```